# Cannot hide status bar if the ViewController is embeded in a NavigationController

Tags: ios, swift

As the title says, I cannot hide the status bar, with the regular `prefersStatusBarHidden` method if my `UIViewController` is within a `UINavigationController`.

If I present a `UIViewController` and the `prefersStatusBarHidden` returns `true` the status bar will be hidden, but if I embed the same `UIViewController` like the following:

```
let vc = VC()
let navc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
present(navc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The `prefersStatusBarHidden` will not be called.

Any hint on why this is happening??

Comment: probably because you need to set prefersStatusBarHidden on the navigationController and not the view controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably this is because you are testing on an iPhone X or similar no-bezel device.  It is impossible to hide the status bar when there's a navigation bar on such a device.

Comment: I think you’re correct. I am indeed testing on an iPhone XS. I guess I’ll have to find another solution